# Asp.net Core 2.1 Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to understand the issue of logging on asp.net cortex 2.1. My goal is to register all critical errors due to which the kestrel server may break. As I understood from the documentation
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
and Serilog, you need to create a logger in each controller, and set the recording conditions (for example try/catch). Is there a more convenient way to log ANY critical errors in a project from one place? I'll be greateful for any help.

Comment: You can use Exception Middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Exception Middleware`. Please see the documentation about [Middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace API.Middlewares
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom Exception middleware to catch unhandled exception during runtime
    /// </summary>
    public class ExceptionMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> _logger;

        public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                // next request in pipeline
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Logs your each error
                _logger.LogError($"Something went wrong: {ex}");
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle runtime error
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="exception"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            // Customise it to handle more complex errors
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            return context.Response.WriteAsync($"Something went wrong: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Then add it in your `Startup.cs`

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // Custom exception middleware
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();;

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**According to [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)**

> The order that middleware components are added in the
>   Startup.Configure method defines the order in which the middleware
>   components are invoked on requests and the reverse order for the
>   response.

So always add `Exception Middleware` as your first **Middleware**, so that it can catch the exception from other **Middlewares** also.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent guide [Net Core Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

#### Exception handler lambda

> An alternative to a custom exception handler page is to provide a lambda to UseExceptionHandler. **Using a lambda allows access to the error before returning the response.**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
   app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
   {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html lang=\"en\"><body>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR!<br><br>\r\n");

            var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = 
                context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

            // Use exceptionHandlerPathFeature to process the exception (for example, 
            // logging), but do NOT expose sensitive error information directly to 
            // the client.

            if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("File error thrown!<br><br>\r\n");
            }

            await context.Response.WriteAsync("<a href=\"/\">Home</a><br>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body></html>\r\n");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(new string(' ', 512)); // IE padding
        });
    });
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

So you can do your logging inside the lamda and catch all exceptions thrown from the web api.

#### Exception filters

> Exception filters are useful for trapping exceptions that occur within MVC actions, but they're not as flexible as the Exception Handling Middleware. We recommend using the middleware. Use filters only where you need to perform error handling differently based on which MVC action is chosen.

#### Custom Exception Middleware

Already mentioned in other answers. Pretty neat guide [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/). I'm only adding a neat way to add extention method as out of the box middlewares.

```
// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware>();
    }
}
```